# What does A| B mean in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have some code that works

```
thing(A|B)
```

However, if I do:

```
Foo = A | B,
thing(Foo)
```

The app doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't work as intended

Why is this happening?

Comment: `foo` is *not* a variable. In Prolog variables start with an *U*ppercase, constants start with a *l*owercase.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem fixed, thanks, but the weirdness still persists (the example above is one I made on the fly to illustrate my main question)

Comment: @pfft: maybe post a more complete example ?

Comment: @pfft - Please don't post code "on the fly". Please test code as much as possible before posting. Otherwise it can be a big waste of time. If you wrote a good question you'd have answers by now.

Comment: it doesn't work because of one reason, or maybe two. This comment is as detailed as your question.